# Minha conta do stack overflow não permite fazer perguntas

Tags: suporte

Boas gostaria de saber porque a minha conta do pt.stackoverflow.com esta bloqueada para fazer pergunta.

Dizem que as minhas perguntas são "fracas"... Gostaria de saber o porque sendo que nao tenho reputação negativa quase em nenhuma.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acima tenho os prints das minhas perguntas, eu não consigo entender o porque do bloqueio sendo que  ultimamente até tenho conseguido evoluir na plataforma, estando nos melhores 6% da semana em #12 lugar. Tenho evoluido bastante na plataforma, tanto em entender as explicações que me dão as minhas perguntas, como tentar sempre responder as perguntas que eu acho que consigo elaborar uma boa resposta.

Apenas gostaria de uma explicação plausível.

Cumprimentos a toda a comunidade.

Comment: Não encontrei bloqueio recente (já teve no passado). Pode ser *bug* (improvável) ou alguma outra coisa. Só note que pode estar indo bem nas respostas e mal nas perguntas o sistema trata as duas de forma independente. Suas perguntas não vão tão bem assim e tem muitas negativas e fechadas, mas tem muita apagada que não aparece na lista, o sistema as considera. A pior coisa que alguém pode fazer é deixar uma pergunta ruim para trás, tem que arrumar, caso contrário o sistema considera que não só tem algo ruim, mas não quis (ou soube) arrumar. Não estou dizendo que foi isto que aconteceu.

Comment: pois, eu tive de apagar algumas perguntas para voltar a conseguir realizar perguntas, tinha uma duvida da qual ainda nem pergunta fiz pelo simples meno de voltar a ficar bloqueado